# Пагинация на странице товаров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

Есть сайт на woocommerce, и на странице товарова нужно вывести пагинацию. Как это сделать?
В гугле находит только пагинацию для wordpress но она не помогает.

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woo_pagination/ это первый результат из гугла

Comment: Непонятно какая такая страница товаров. Если это стандартный каталог, то пагинация есть из коробки в любой нормальной теме.

Comment: Тему с нуля делаю

Comment: @Oleg отсюда все проблемы. Берите стандартную или любую понравившуюся из репозитория, от неё дочернюю, и учите, как там сделано.

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Answer (score 0):

Правильный способ выйти из положения, это открыть шаблон WooCommmerce и посмотреть как сделано там.
Например - archive-product.php

У меня была задача, где мне нужно было продублировать пагинацию в шаблоне, таким образом, что бы она была не только внизу, но и вверху.
Я добавил в functions.php, следующий код:

```
// добавляем пагинацию вверху цикла магазина
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );
```

**У меня выводится. Надеюсь, это Вам поможет.**

Естественно у меня в шаблоне предусмотрены области/хуки:

**do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );**

и

**do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );**

Для того, что бы я мог в нужные места, посредством хука вставлять свой код или менять его логику.